# TYPO3 | Extbase | Domain Model | Lifecycle Hooks

Tags: extbase, typo3-6.2.x

After hours and hours where I searched the whole universe for an answer, I decided to ask you clever guys again.

I' working on Typo3 6.2.
I've written an Extbase extension including domain models, which is working fine.
Instead of custom backend modules, the domain models are managed by the list module shipped with Typo3.

One of those domain models contains a property which has to be filled when the object is created/updated. After alot of research, I was sure that the signal dispatcher is my way to go, but I failed to get it triggered in any way.

So my question:

How can I register a "callback" which is called when an Extbase domain model has been created/updated using Typo3 6.2?

Comment: Is the domain model edited in the backend or the frontend? - I do not know of a single way of doing this in both front and back-end but you could use TCEMain hook in the backend and either integrate some magic in your model or repository. I am not familiar working with 'signal dispatcher' - i only knows the name.

Comment: I guess you could use the ```__construct``` method of that Model. Check in there if its a new object or existing one and do your logic.